# How do I truncate a string and return both first and last part without a center part?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate

Let `string_a = "I'm a very long long long string"`

Is there a method in Ruby that truncates a string something like this?:

```
magic_method(string_a) # => "I'm a ver...ng string"
```

In Rails I can do: `truncate(string_a)` but only the first part is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the method `String.scan` with a regular expression to break the string where you wish. Try somenthing like:

```
def magic_method(string_x)
    splits = string_x.scan(/(.{0,9})(.*?)(.{0,9}$)/)[0]
    splits[1] = "..." if splits[1].length > 3
    splits.join
end
```

Explanation:
 Supose `string_a = "I'm a very long long long string"`; `string_b = "A small test string"`; and `string_c = "tiny"`. First split the string within 3 groups.

- The first group `(.{0,9})` try to catch the first 9 or less characters. Ex. `"I'm a ver"`  for `string_a`; `"A small t"` for `string_b` and `"tiny"` for `string_c`.
- The last group `(.{0,9}$)` try to catch the last 9 or less characters and the end of string (`$`). Ex.`"ng string"` for `string_a`; `"st string"` for `string_b` and `""` for `string_c`;
- The middle group `(.*?)` try to catch what is left over. This only works because of the `?` that makes this regular expression not greedy (otherwise it would get the rest of the string, lefting nothing to the last group. Ex: `"y long long lo"` for `string_a`, `"e"` for `string_b` and `""` for `string_c`

Than we check if the middle group is greater than 3 characters, if so, we replace with `"..."`. This will only happen on `string_a`. Here we wouldn't like to make `string_b` longer, replacing `"e"` with `"..."` resulting in `"A simple t...st string"`.

Finally join the groups (array elements) into a single string with `Array.join`

Comment: Very elegant. The results are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Why not try something like:

```
s[0..l] + "..." + s[s.length-l..s.length]
```

with l * 2 + 3 being the desired length, so perhaps a method something like this

```
def middle_truncate(s,length=20,ellipsis="...")
 return s if s.length <= length + ellipsis.length
 return s[0..length] if length < ellipsis.length
 len = (length - ellipsis.length)/2 
 s_len = len - length % 2
 s[0..s_len] + ellipsis + s[s.length-len..s.length]
end

s ="I'm a very long long long string"
puts middle_truncate(s, 100) 
puts middle_truncate(s, 21) 
puts middle_truncate(s, 11) 
puts middle_truncate(s, 5) 
puts middle_truncate(s*2, 45)
puts middle_truncate(s)
puts middle_truncate(s,2)
```

outputs

```
I'm a very long long long string
I'm a ver...ng string
I'm ...ring
I...g
I'm a very long long ...long long long string
I'm a ver...g string
I'm
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post

Comment: This is too simplistic. `middle_truncate('foo', 10)
=> "foo...foo"` which isn't usable.

Comment: So it needs a check for someone asking to truncate a string shorter than the length, will add to the method above.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
ELLIPSIS = "..."
DEFAULT_MAX_LEN = 15

def trunc_to_len(string, len = DEFAULT_MAX_LEN)
    return "" if len <= 0
    return "." * len if len < ELLIPSIS.length + 2
    return string if string.length <= len

    # make room for "..."
    half = (len - ELLIPSIS.length) / 2
    string[0,half] + ELLIPSIS + string[-half,half]
end
```

These examples:

```
puts trunc_to_len("I'm a very long long long string", 100)
puts trunc_to_len("I'm a very long long long string", 21)
puts trunc_to_len("I'm a very long long long string", 11)
puts trunc_to_len("I'm a very long long long string", 5)
puts trunc_to_len("I'm a very long long long string")
puts trunc_to_len("I'm a very long long long string",2)
```

output:

```
I'm a very long long long string
I'm a ver...ng string
I'm ...ring
I...g
I'm a ...string
..
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
str[9..-10] = "..."
p str #=> "abcdefghi...rstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def trunc_to_len(s, n)
  if n < s.length
    i, j = n.divmod 2
    s[0..i+j-1] + "..." + s[-i..-1]
  else
    s
  end 
end
```